# R Group Hours by Text

Tags: r

Hi I am trying to group 24 hours into three groups as follows below in a new column:

```
Year  Hours  Users
2021    0     2332323
2021    1     2222323
2021    2     6332323
2021    3     9222323
###etc up to hours 23
```

My goal is to add a new column which gives each time a specific time of day text as follows, with the goal of having an end new column with hours 5 to 12 as "Morning", 13 TO 20 as "Evening", and lastly, 21 to 4 as "Night". Can anyone help to understand how I should create this column?

```
Year  Hours  Users      HourType
2021    0     2332323    Night
2021    1     2222323    Night
2021    2     6332323    Night
2021    3     9222323    Night
2021    4     1222323    Morning
2021    5     1222323    Morning
###etc up to hours 23
```

Comment: Use the cut() function: `cut(0:24, breaks=c(0, 4, 12, 20, 24), labels=c("Night", "Morn", "Eve", "Night"), include.lowest = TRUE)`

Comment: @Dave2e That could just be 0:23, otherwise looks like a solid answer.